# lost user  + how to get my user back in serverfault site

Tags: support, status-completed

please advice

I ask this question

[shell script (KSH) + set file to param & perform test between param and string](https://serverfault.com/questions/356914/shell-script-ksh-set-file-to-param-perform-test-between-param-and-string)

but from some reason my user not apears in the serverfault site
so I cant back and edit my question
please advice how to restore my Eytan user in serverfault site?

Comment: I think this should be asked on meta

Answer (score 2):

I have merged your accounts together. Because you are an un-registered account, a change of computer or cookies etc will cause you to lose your association.

I suggest you log in using a real account (you can log in with your [Yahoo account](http://openid.yahoo.com/), even), then you'll never lose your account again.